# How to auto resfreh a div with smooth animation

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML page where I like to smoothly resfreh a div every 60 seconds.

What I have in mind is this:

*fade out div /
refresh div /
fade in div*

Just that! I read a lot of jQuery and AJAX stuff about refresh pages/div but I can't make it fine.

My actual code is:

```
$('#content').fadeOut(500, function show_data() {
$(this).html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="URL" />').fadeIn(500);
setInterval('show_data()', 10000);
});
```

If anyone could help me, I thank you.

Comment: Show us what you already tried yourself, it helps us to answer your question from your code context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that as you've read about it you already know how to do the basics and the AJAX call. It would be helpful if you'd let us know in the question where you're up to :)

In the AJAX success function add this:

```
$('#divId').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).text('New text!').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, but there is something that is passing me by.
The code is this:

$('#content').fadeOut(500, function show_data() {
    $(this).html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="URL" />').fadeIn(500);
 setInterval('show_data()', 10000);

});

There is something wrong, right?

Comment: Can you tell us what your code currently does and how you are using it?

Comment: In fact, the actual code does nothing of what I would like to. The actual div just show a 100% height and width iframe page. I like it to refresh that page smoothly.